# req object in passport.authenticate

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am using passportjs for authentication on my server. I am using the following code:

```
exports.auth = function(req, res, next){
  passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false })(req, res, next);
};

passport.use(new BearerStrategy(
  function(token, done) {
    User.findOne({ token: token }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false);
      }
      return done(null, user, { scope: 'read' });
    });
  }
));
```

Is there a way to access the req object in passport.use? This was I can get the user ip address and check for eventual attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments in the [example](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http-bearer/blob/master/examples/bearer/app.js#L52) suggest that you can pass an object `{ "passReqToCallback": true }` to make the req callback available in the callback function. Which can be accessed as

`function(req, token, done){//rest of the function body}`

So initialize passport.use as

```
passport.use(new BearerStrategy({ "passReqToCallback": true },

 function(req, token, done) {
  });
```

and you should have req in the callback.